# Is it possible to specify type parameters for String Interpolation in Scala

Tags: scala, string-interpolation

```
implicit class Interpolator(val a: StringContext) extends AnyVal {
  def foo[A](args: Any*): A = ???
}

val first  = foo[String]"myString" // This does not parse
val second = (new StringContext).foo[String]("myString") // This works but I'm wondering if there is a more concise syntax
val third = foo"myString"[String] // This one is intriguing because it parses but the compiler outputs "method foo does not take type parameters"... what?
```

If `A` can be inferred then it's all good because `foo"myString"` will simply work but if it can't I am wondering if there is a better syntax than `second` that allows me to specify the type parameter I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second only compile but it doesn't really work, we can try for example

```
implicit class Interpolator(val a: StringContext) {
    def foo[A](args: Any*): A = args.head.asInstanceOf[A]
}

val a = 2
val second = (new StringContext)foo[String]"a=$a"
println(second)// this will print a=$a which is not the expected output
```

But the following should work

```
implicit class Interpolator[A](val a: StringContext)  {
    def foo(args: Any*): A = args.head.asInstanceOf[A]
}

val a = 2
val first :Int = foo"a=$a" // : Int is what that does the trick
println(first) // will print 2 as expected
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question which is how to supply type arguments when using string interpolator syntax. Although the behavior of the first code sample is odd indeed I will admit.

Comment: Because a new Interpolator is created for every run of foo then supply the type arguments to Interpolator is the same as supply them to foo. In my example they are supplied implicitly ... ( by assigning to an int val) . So it is an answer to your question, if i'm missing something , can u supply  a code example so ill understand what u r trying to do ?

Comment: I see. But the type argument still needs to be inferred which is why I am asking: how can it be specified? I wish it could simply be inferred in the case I am dealing with as it would make things much simpler for me, but unfortunately, that's not the case. But I am curious now why the second example behaves differently than the first one? What's happening in the first one to produce the unexpected result?

Comment: And I also just noticed that there are two differences between your first code sample and the second one. The way `Interpolator` introduces the type argument but also how the string interpolation is used. Do you have reason to believe that inference works better if `A` is a parameter of `Interpolator` instead of `foo`?

Comment: Try to check http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/StringContext.html in order to understand why the first example act weird, generally its because that there is a lot of "synthetic shugar" involved , and u need to call foo with only (a) as param and not with "a=$a" , this happens implicitly on the second example (yes scala is sometime a bitch) . My reason to believe that its better create the Interpolator with type argument is because it makes the synthetic shugar possible. Scala can't create it if the type is on the function...